# Spring mvc + Spring Jpa + tyhmleaf StackOverflowError

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I'm working with spring boot and thymeleaf as template engine, when i tried to use Spring JPA method **findAllByPropertyTitleContainning**, i had **StackOverflowError**

**Property.class**

```
package com.example.estateagencyspring.models;

import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Data
public class Property {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String propertyTitle;
    private String propertyDescription;
    private String location;
    private String type;
    private String status;
    private String area;
    private String beds;
    private String baths;
    private String garage;
    private String defaultPicture;
    private String price;
    @Lob
    private String googleSrc;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy="property")
    private List<Picture> pictures = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "property_amenity",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "property_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "amenity_id")
    )
    private List<Amenity> amenities = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

this code of Amenity class, it has **@ManyToMany** relationship with Property class
**Amenity.class**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Data
public class Amenity {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "amenities", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Property> properties = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

**PropertyRepository.class**

```
public interface PropertyRepository extends JpaRepository<Property, String> {

    Optional<Property> findByPropertyTitle(String title);

    List<Property> findAllByPropertyTitleContaining(String title);

}
```

**PropertyService.class**

```
...
public List<Property> searchByTitle(String title){
        System.out.println(propertyRepository.findAllByPropertyTitleContaining(title));
        return propertyRepository.findAllByPropertyTitleContaining(title);
    }
```

Comment: You have a `Property` which has an `Amenity` which has a `List<Property>` which each have an `Amenity` which each have a ... and on and on and on .... You need to mark which to use as a reference in JSON and which not.

Comment: I just noticed that the problem is in printing method, i mean if i don't print result the app work fine, the StackOverflowError appear when i use print method.

Comment: That is because of your use of `@Data`... Generally don't use `@Data` for entities that is a bad idea... I've written about that a while ago see -> https://deinum.biz/2019-02-13-Lombok-Data-Ojects-Arent-Entities/

Comment: i'll read about it, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I changed `@Data` to `@Setter` and `@Getter`. Printing method works fine. Thank you very much.